# How to set focus on NSTableView with selected row

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have a NSTableView and my data source is organised from A to Z. I want to set the default value in initialisation.
I can set the selected row by

`tableView.selectRowIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: 25), byExtendingSelection: false)`

It works. However, I have to scroll down to 'Z' to find out what exactly it is.

How can I focus on that row in the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override this method (iOS), definitely there would be some similar method in OSX

public func scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath, atScrollPosition scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)

after the moment your table gets loaded 
Than you can pass indexpath value to your first row.

Hope this works to you.

Comment: Thanks.  I found `func scrollRowToVisible(row: Int)` in OS X and it works!